# ExpressionEngine Query Results in Another Query

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

I have two queries. I want the results of one query to be the IN of another. I have tried numerous solutions today, including PHP (which requires one parse input and one parse output, so it doesn't work), and it just isn't working. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM exp_relationships WHERE child_id = {entry_id} AND grid_field_id IN (90, 91, 112)" backspace="2"}{parent_id}, {/exp:query}
{exp:query sql="SELECT field_id_16 AS firstyear FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id IN ('RESULTSHERE') ORDER BY firstyear ASC LIMIT 1"}
    {exp:ce_str:ing truncate="4||yes"}{firstyear}{/exp:ce_str:ing}
{/exp:query}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can put a query inside the IN clause of another:

```
SELECT field_id_16 AS firstyear 
FROM exp_channel_data 
WHERE 
  entry_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM exp_relationships WHERE child_id = {entry_id} AND grid_field_id IN (90, 91, 112)
  ) 
ORDER BY firstyear ASC LIMIT 1
```